# Sending solution to new developer with tfs - package issues

Tags: c#, visual-studio, tfs, nuget

I have shared a solution with another developer via TFS and we are having some trouble with the packages.

In the source control explorer I see what is shared is a packages folder with each package folder and a `.nupkg` file in each.

I read that we needed to run `Update-Package` to install all of these based on the packages.config folder. When we did that there was an error on EntityFramework. Here are the logs.

```
No package updates are available from the current package source for project 'ConfigManager'.
Attempting to gather dependency information for multiple packages with respect to project 'BusinessServices.Tests', targeting '.NETFramework,Version=v4.5'
Attempting to resolve dependencies for multiple packages.
Resolving actions install multiple packages
Removed package 'NUnit 3.2.1' from 'packages.config'
Successfully uninstalled 'NUnit 3.2.1' from BusinessServices.Tests
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/nunit/3.5.0/nunit.3.5.0.nupkg
  OK https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/nunit/3.5.0/nunit.3.5.0.nupkg 56ms
Installing NUnit 3.5.0.
Adding package 'NUnit.3.5.0' to folder 'C:\WORK\TFS\TransitProjects\HmkApi\packages'
Added package 'NUnit.3.5.0' to folder 'C:\WORK\TFS\TransitProjects\HmkApi\packages'
Added package 'NUnit.3.5.0' to 'packages.config'
Successfully installed 'NUnit 3.5.0' to BusinessServices.Tests
Removing package 'NUnit 3.2.1' from folder 'C:\WORK\TFS\TransitProjects\HmkApi\packages'
Removed package 'NUnit 3.2.1' from folder 'C:\WORK\TFS\TransitProjects\HmkApi\packages'
Attempting to gather dependency information for multiple packages with respect to project 'PrintServices.Tests', targeting '.NETFramework,Version=v4.5'
Attempting to resolve dependencies for multiple packages.
Resolving actions install multiple packages
Removed package 'NUnit 2.6.4' from 'packages.config'
Successfully uninstalled 'NUnit 2.6.4' from PrintServices.Tests
Removed package 'Moq 4.5.9' from 'packages.config'
Successfully uninstalled 'Moq 4.5.9' from PrintServices.Tests
Executing script file 'C:\WORK\TFS\TransitProjects\HmkApi\packages\AutoMapper.3.3.1\tools\net40\uninstall.ps1'
Removed package 'AutoMapper 3.3.1' from 'packages.config'
Successfully uninstalled 'AutoMapper 3.3.1' from PrintServices.Tests
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/automapper/5.1.1/automapper.5.1.1.nupkg
  OK https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/automapper/5.1.1/automapper.5.1.1.nupkg 120ms
Installing AutoMapper 5.1.1.
Adding package 'AutoMapper.5.1.1' to folder 'C:\WORK\TFS\TransitProjects\HmkApi\packages'
Added package 'AutoMapper.5.1.1' to folder 'C:\WORK\TFS\TransitProjects\HmkApi\packages'
Added package 'AutoMapper.5.1.1' to 'packages.config'
Successfully installed 'AutoMapper 5.1.1' to PrintServices.Tests
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/moq/4.5.28/moq.4.5.28.nupkg
  OK https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/moq/4.5.28/moq.4.5.28.nupkg 113ms
Installing Moq 4.5.28.
Adding package 'Moq.4.5.28' to folder 'C:\WORK\TFS\TransitProjects\HmkApi\packages'
Added package 'Moq.4.5.28' to folder 'C:\WORK\TFS\TransitProjects\HmkApi\packages'
Added package 'Moq.4.5.28' to 'packages.config'
Successfully installed 'Moq 4.5.28' to PrintServices.Tests
Package 'NUnit.3.5.0' already exists in folder 'C:\WORK\TFS\TransitProjects\HmkApi\packages'
Added package 'NUnit.3.5.0' to 'packages.config'
Successfully installed 'NUnit 3.5.0' to PrintServices.Tests
Removing package 'AutoMapper 3.3.1' from folder 'C:\WORK\TFS\TransitProjects\HmkApi\packages'
Removed package 'AutoMapper 3.3.1' from folder 'C:\WORK\TFS\TransitProjects\HmkApi\packages'
Attempting to gather dependency information for multiple packages with respect to project 'PrintServices', targeting '.NETFramework,Version=v4.5'
Attempting to resolve dependencies for multiple packages.
Resolving actions install multiple packages
Removed package 'NLog 4.3.3' from 'packages.config'
Successfully uninstalled 'NLog 4.3.3' from PrintServices
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/nlog/4.3.11/nlog.4.3.11.nupkg
  OK https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/nlog/4.3.11/nlog.4.3.11.nupkg 283ms
Installing NLog 4.3.11.
Adding package 'NLog.4.3.11' to folder 'C:\WORK\TFS\TransitProjects\HmkApi\packages'
Added package 'NLog.4.3.11' to folder 'C:\WORK\TFS\TransitProjects\HmkApi\packages'
Added package 'NLog.4.3.11' to 'packages.config'
Successfully installed 'NLog 4.3.11' to PrintServices
Attempting to gather dependency information for multiple packages with respect to project 'Resolver', targeting '.NETFramework,Version=v4.5'
Attempting to resolve dependencies for multiple packages.
Resolving actions install multiple packages
Removed package 'Unity 2.1.505.0' from 'packages.config'
Successfully uninstalled 'Unity 2.1.505.0' from Resolver
Removed package 'CommonServiceLocator 1.0' from 'packages.config'
Successfully uninstalled 'CommonServiceLocator 1.0' from Resolver
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/commonservicelocator/1.3.0/commonservicelocator.1.3.0.nupkg
  OK https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/commonservicelocator/1.3.0/commonservicelocator.1.3.0.nupkg 8ms
Installing CommonServiceLocator 1.3.0.
Adding package 'CommonServiceLocator.1.3.0' to folder 'C:\WORK\TFS\TransitProjects\HmkApi\packages'
Added package 'CommonServiceLocator.1.3.0' to folder 'C:\WORK\TFS\TransitProjects\HmkApi\packages'
Added package 'CommonServiceLocator.1.3.0' to 'packages.config'
Successfully installed 'CommonServiceLocator 1.3.0' to Resolver
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/unity/4.0.1/unity.4.0.1.nupkg
  OK https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/unity/4.0.1/unity.4.0.1.nupkg 4ms
Installing Unity 4.0.1.
Adding package 'Unity.4.0.1' to folder 'C:\WORK\TFS\TransitProjects\HmkApi\packages'
Added package 'Unity.4.0.1' to folder 'C:\WORK\TFS\TransitProjects\HmkApi\packages'
Added package 'Unity.4.0.1' to 'packages.config'
Successfully installed 'Unity 4.0.1' to Resolver
Attempting to gather dependency information for multiple packages with respect to project 'BusinessServices', targeting '.NETFramework,Version=v4.5'
Attempting to resolve dependencies for multiple packages.
Resolving actions install multiple packages
Removed package 'NLog 4.3.3' from 'packages.config'
Successfully uninstalled 'NLog 4.3.3' from BusinessServices
Removed package 'EntityFramework 5.0.0' from 'packages.config'
Successfully uninstalled 'EntityFramework 5.0.0' from BusinessServices
Removed package 'AutoMapper 4.2.1' from 'packages.config'
Successfully uninstalled 'AutoMapper 4.2.1' from BusinessServices
Package 'AutoMapper.5.1.1' already exists in folder 'C:\WORK\TFS\TransitProjects\HmkApi\packages'
Added package 'AutoMapper.5.1.1' to 'packages.config'
Successfully installed 'AutoMapper 5.1.1' to BusinessServices
Package 'EntityFramework.6.1.3' already exists in folder 'C:\WORK\TFS\TransitProjects\HmkApi\packages'
Install failed. Rolling back...
Package 'EntityFramework 6.1.3' does not exist in project 'BusinessServices'
Removed package 'AutoMapper 5.1.1' from 'packages.config'
Package 'AutoMapper 4.2.1' already exists in folder 'C:\WORK\TFS\TransitProjects\HmkApi\packages'
Package 'EntityFramework 5.0.0' already exists in folder 'C:\WORK\TFS\TransitProjects\HmkApi\packages'
Package 'NLog 4.3.3' already exists in folder 'C:\WORK\TFS\TransitProjects\HmkApi\packages'
Removing package 'EntityFramework 6.1.3' from folder 'C:\WORK\TFS\TransitProjects\HmkApi\packages'
Removed package 'EntityFramework 6.1.3' from folder 'C:\WORK\TFS\TransitProjects\HmkApi\packages'
Update-Package : Failed to add reference to 'EntityFramework'.
At line:1 char:1
+ Update-Package
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Update-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.UpdatePackageCommand
```

At this point I am pretty stuck, not sure what my options are?

Comment: What version of VS are you using?

Comment: 2013... I may just need to run again but with `Update-Package -reinstall` - going to try that shortly

Comment: I'm assuming you have committed the `Packages` folder in source control. Second you don't need to run the `Update-package` command. It will update the package version from Nuget source instead  of Restoring them.

Comment: Did you check in all the nuget packages into source control?